# How can mergeMap work when we expect errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a very specific use case, we have 200 images and we want to load them 10 at a time. MergeMap with concurrency is the perfect method in rxjs for this kind of use case with 200 HTTP requests and executing them 10 at a time. But images might fail, and that's ok in our system, we might try to get an image that no longer exists and that throws an HTTP error and here is the problem:

In MergeMap, if one of the observables fails, I only get the error and all other requests get canceled or blocked. I added catchError in every level of execution to test if I can catch it and return a non-error observable without success.

Is there a way to use MergeMap concurrency where we expect errors and execute all of them?

My code:

```
const limitedParallelObservableExecution = <T>(
                    listOfItems: T[],
                    observableMethod: (item: T) => Observable<unknown>,
                    maxConcurrency: number = maxParallelUploads
                ): Observable<unknown> => {
                    if (listOfItems && listOfItems.length > 0) {
                        const observableListOfItems: Observable<T> = from(listOfItems);
                        return observableListOfItems.pipe(mergeMap(observableMethod, maxConcurrency), toArray());
                    } else {
                        return of({});
                    }
                };
```

And I execute it here:

```
limitedParallelObservableExecution<T>(queueImages, (item) =>
                    methodReturnsObservable().pipe(
                        catchError((error) => {
                            // Catch error and returns Observable
                            return of([]);
                        })
                    )
                ).subscribe((value) => console.log('value: ', value));
```

The last console.log in the subscribe never gets executed.

EDIT:
Indeed seems like the content of the 'methodReturnsObservable()' is the culprit:

```
downloadVehicleImage(imageId: string, width: number): Observable<any> {
        const params = objectToActualHttpParams({
            width,
            noSpinner: true
        });
        return this.http.get(`${environment.WS_ENDPOINT_URI}/vehicles/image/${imageId}`, { responseType: 'blob', params }).pipe(
            mergeMap((blob) => {
                if (blob.size > 0) {
                    const image = new Subject();

                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                    reader.onloadend = () => image.next(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(reader.result as string));

                    return image.asObservable();
                }

                return of();
            })
        );
    }
```

Removing the pipe out of the http.get solves my issue, so I will debug this to see what's wrong, thanks!

Comment: What you've written works for me when I stub it out. My guess is your error is elsewhere. `methodReturnsObservable` must complete or error. If any of them stay open, toArray() will never emit.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the contents of methodReturnsObservable? I would think that you would have to catch the error there if you'd want to continue.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written works for me when I stub it out. My guess is your error is elsewhere. methodReturnsObservable must complete or error. If any of them stay open, toArray() will never emit.

One way to check that is with a timeout

```ts
function limitedParallelObservableExecution<T, R>(
  listOfItems: T[],
  observableMethod: (item: T) => Observable<R>,
  maxConcurrency: number = maxParallelUploads
): Observable<R[]> {

  return from(listOfItems || []).pipe(
    mergeMap(
      item => observableMethod(v).pipe(
        timeout({ each: 5000 }),
        catchError(_ => EMPTY)
      ),
      maxConcurrency
    ),
    toArray()
  );

}
```

Comment: You are right, I updated the question with the content of the 'methodReturnsObservable' and indeed affected to the stream, I removed it and works fine, so I will just figure out what's wrong in there, thanks!